# Knowing the distribution of $(X,Y)$ implies knowing the distribution of $(X,Y, X-Y)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider a random vector $(X,Y)$ and suppose we know the **joint** probability distribution $P$ of $(X,Y)$.

Does this mean that we know (although maybe hard to derive analytically in many cases) the **joint** probability distribution of $(X,Y, X-Y)$? I understand that the marginals are all known, but I have doubts on the **joint**.

Can you provide an example to corroborate your answer, e.g.,
$$
(X,Y)\sim \mathcal{N}((0,0), \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma^2_1 & \sigma_{12}\\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma^2_2\\
\end{pmatrix})
$$

Comment: Of course. Informally: if we know the joint probability of $(X,Y)$ we know (at the probabilistic level) "everything" about them. So for any random variables that are function of them (and only them), say $(Z_1=g_1(X,Y), Z_2=g_2(X,Y) \cdots )$, we also know the joint probability (i.e. "everything").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is the (continuous) mapping $(x,y)\to(x,y,x-y)$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^3$, then the joint distribution of $(X,Y,X-Y)$ is the probability measure $Q$ given by $Q(B)=P(f^{-1}(B))$, for Borel sets $B\subset\Bbb R^3$. This provides a rather abstract YES answer to your question.

In your normal example, because $f$ is linear, the vector $(X,Y,X-Y)$ has a (degenerate) joint normal distribution, with zero means and covariance matrix
$$
\left[\matrix{\sigma_1^2&\sigma_{12}&\sigma_1^2-\sigma_{12}\cr \sigma_{12}&\sigma_2^2&\sigma_{12}-\sigma_2^2\cr \sigma_1^2-\sigma_{12}&\sigma_{12}-\sigma_2^2&\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2-2\sigma_{12}\cr}\right].
$$
(*Degenerate* because this covariance matrix has rank at most 2.)

Comment: Just a silly clarification: "degenerate" does not mean that $(X,Y,X-Y)$ is a degenerate random vector (i.e., taking one value only), correct?

Comment: Sorry.  By "degenerate" I meant that the 3-dimensional random vector $(X,Y,X-Y)$ takes values in a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ of dimension less than 3.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let $Z=X-Y$. Then,

$p(X=x, Y=y, Z=z) = \begin{cases} p(X=x, Y=y), \text{ if } z=x-y \\
0, \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$